# Replace specific Objects in IQueryable query in .NET fails

Tags: sql, .net, linq, api

i have two querys(IQueryable) written in query syntax in my .NET Web API. They both return DTO Models.

First query returns all Objects with an empty Text Field(ApplicationSettingsto.Text).
Second query return specific Objects which contain some information in Text Field(ApplicationSettingsto.Text).

My goal is to replace only specific entities from first query which have the same KeyName (query1.DTO.KeyName == query2.DTO.KeyName), so that my output contains some objects with empty TextField and some objects with informations in TextField.

Can I use to the query syntax for this or do I need to change to method syntax?

Below my DTO Model and the querys:

DTO Model

```
public class ApplicationSettingsDto
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }

    // User View
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Typ { get; set; }

    // '*' if Node else some value
    public string Wert { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string DefaultValues { get; set; }

    public bool IsNode { get; set; }

}
```

Querys(IQueryable):

```
// For simplicity I left out the detailed query
var query1; // returns all DTOs with empty Text Field
var query2; // returns only DTOs which contain Informations in Text Field

// This is the query part I don't understand how to implement
var result; // Should replace the specific objects from query1 with objects from query2 if (query2.Object.KeyName.Equals(query1.Object.KeyName))
```

Many Thanks in Advance ;)

Comment: can you write the sample code

Comment: What do you mean by sample Code? I search for example impementation code for the last query? Do you mean the code from query1 and query2?

Comment: the detailed query

Comment: You can try LINQ's Join and GroupJoin - if whatever you are querying provides implementations for them. Edulinq's examples by Jon Skeet: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join/  and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-22-groupjoin/ . Great series by the way, that I highly recommend.

Comment: GroupJoin did it's job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't mention it, let's assume your queries contain the same type of elements. So it is not that the first sequence contains strings and the second sequence contains `DateTimes`.

```
IQueryable<TSource> query1 = ...
IQueryable<TSource> query2 = ...
```

Therefore, if you only replace some elements from query1 with elements from query2, then the result is of course also an `IQueryable<TSource>`.

You didn't specify what you want if there are several objects in query2 with the same `KeyName`, worse: if there are also several objects in query1 with the same `KeyName`.

And what if one of the elements in your query has a null `Object`? In that case you can't ask for `Object.KeyName`.

Let's assume all elements have a non-null `Object`, and all `KeyNames` are unique.

The solution is a GroupJoin on common `Object.KeyName`, if an item in `query1` has one or more query2 items with the same `Object.KeyName`, take one of the query2 items (let's take the first, shall we?), if there are no matching q2, take the q1

```
var result = query1
    .GroupJoin(query2,             // GroupJoin query1 and query2
        q1 => q1.Object.KeyName,   // from every query1 element take Object.KeyName
        q2 => q2.Object.KeyName,   // from every query2 element take Object.KeyName
        (q1, matchingQ2s) =>       // from every q1 with all its matching q2 objects
                                   // take the first matching q2, or q1 if there is none
            matchingQ2s.FirstOrDefault() ?? q1

  );
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this approach later.
All queries are type IQueryable<ApplicationSettingsDto>, also result query.
Check for Null Objects is already implemented, it is only a one-to-one relationship .

Comment: Does it's job perfectly!!
I ask myself wether this approach using lambda expression would als work with
query1.zip(...)

Comment: It would only work with Zip if the first element of `query1` had to compare with the first element of `query2`, and the second element of `query1` had to compare with the second element of `query2`. It would give different results if the `KeyName` of the 3rd element of `query1` matches the `KeyName` of the 1st element of `query2`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var results = query1.ForEachAsync(q1 => 
              {
                 var matchedKeyName = query2.FirstOrDefault(q2 => q2.DTO.KeyName == 
                                                                  q1.DTO.KeyName);
                 if (matchedKeyName != null)
                 {
                     q1.DTO.Text = matchedKeyName.DTO.Text;
                 }
              });
```

Comment: ForEach is a List<T> method, not IQueryable

Comment: I guess this would only work if my method where I place my queries, does not return an IQueryable.

Because result query is now of type System.Threading.Tasks.Task,